# Is it safe to store pointer of STL list iterator?

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

I know any insert or remove operations of STL list never invalidate their iterator.
However, I'm not sure whether list still preserves iterator itself or not.

So, can I store pointer of list iterator and use it later?

Comment: `std::list` does not expose any iterator references. Some sample code would make it easier to understand what you mean.

Comment: Ok I got it. begin() or another methods return the copy of iterator, not a reference of iterator. So this is not possible because storing pointer to the local variable is unsafe. Am I right?

Comment: @ljh131 Storing pointer to the local variable is unsafe if you let pointer live longer than the stack frame on which this local variable was created. If you stop using pointer before the variable exits its scope, then you are OK (not that this is particularly useful in most cases).

Comment: Yea. I didn't notice begin() returns copy of iterator.

Answer (score 3):

For an **[std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/)**:

In case of **Insertion**,
All iterators and references unaffected [23.2.2.3/1]

In case of **Erase**,
Only the iterators and references to the erased element get invalidated [23.2.2.3/3]

So, Its safe as long as you erase an element and don't use its stored Iterator.

Comment: ljh131 mentioned iterator pointer in the question. You should mention a copy of the iterator value needs to be stored.